# Microsoft Surface Windows 8 expiration date?

Tags: windows-8

I've got a Microsoft Surface with Windows 8 but when I entered system info it said that the Windows key will be expiring in five months! How is that possible?  Does it mean that my Windows is pirated?

Comment: Looks like a virus or malware: http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/25uin5/windows_81_license_is_expiring_in_6_days_for_no/

Comment: You bought this device from Microsoft tor a third-party?

Comment: @Ramhound I bought from microsoft but recently I gave it to a repairing company to fix it and they told me that they've reinstalled original windows but they only charged me 25bucks, how they have installed original windows??? P.S software pirating is okay in my country

Comment: @omidh - Its possible they didn't use a legitimate license.  You should ask them, if they did, then you should use the embedded license and activate your installation.  You should also upgrade to Windows 8.1.  We are talking about the Surface Pro and not a Surface RT?

Comment: @Ramhound yes it's pro and I can't upgrade it to 8.1, It's illegal version I Think

Comment: @omidh - All Surface devices come with a legitimate license.  So use the embedded license to activate your installation.  Why, Exactly, can't you upgrade to Windows 8.1 all Surface devices support Windows 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound Where can I find embedded license??

Comment: [here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-retrieve-windows-8-oem-product-key-from-bios/) there are existing answers to that question that exist on this website also.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, I found it. But I don't want to use it in a pirated version and I want to install a fresh one, does my key works with windows 8.1 or I must install 8?

Comment: Your asking questions that have been already answered before.  You don't need to reinstall Windows 8.1 a Windows 8.0 key can activate a Windows 8.1 installation just not install Windows 8.1 which is the reason its suggested that you go through the Windows Store to update to Windows 8.1.  All you should have to do is change your current license key to the legitimate then update to Windows 8.1 if that isn't what you want to do then you will have to format your system and then reinstall Windows 8.0 yourself.

Comment: "software pirating is okay in my country" - Really? Which country is this that *legally* allows software piracy?

Comment: @Karan Iran does....

Comment: Weird, even for software developed in Iran? (Or perhaps there's next to none due to that law...)

Comment: @Karan Yeah, Why would anyone pay for a software when thousands of them are available for 2 dollars? The law allows people to pirate because it thinks that it can damage USA technology with this system but It damaged ourself instead, However I can see so much improvement these days because many people prefer original software specially in mobile development area.